Relationship between coupling strength in cross-resonance gates and coefficients in Hamiltonian tomography?
In the effective Hamiltonian for the cross-resonance (CR) gate, the interaction term is written as:
$$
\tilde{H}_{\rm eff}^{\rm CR} = - \frac{\Delta_{12}}{2}\sigma_1^z 
+ \frac{\Omega(t)}{2} \left(\sigma_2^x - \frac{J}{2\Delta_{12}} \sigma_1^z \sigma_2^x \right),\tag{1}
$$
in which
J represents the coupling strength between the control and target qubits.
During Hamiltonian tomography, the Hamiltonian is expressed as:
$$
\hat{H} = \frac{\hat{Z} \otimes \hat{A}}{2} + \frac{\hat{I} \otimes \hat{B}}{2} = 
a_{x} \hat{Z}\hat{X} + a_{y} \hat{Z}\hat{Y} + a_{z} \hat{Z}\hat{Z} + b_{x}  \hat{I}\hat{X} + b_{y} \hat{I}\hat{Y} + b_{z} \hat{I}\hat{Z}  .\tag{2}
$$
Is the coupling strength J in the effective Hamiltonian same as to the coefficient
$_{x}$ obtained from Hamiltonian tomography?
If not, what is the relationship. (For context I am trying to obtain the qubit-qubit coupling on IBM quantum computers).

In your Eq. 1, the $ZX$ coupling strength is given by:
$$
\tag{1}
-\frac{\Omega(t)J}{4\Delta_{12}},
$$
whereas in your Eq. 2 the $ZX$ coupling strength is given by $a_x$.
Therefore, the relationship between $J$ and the fitted $a_x$ value obtained via tomography experiments would be:
$$J \approx \left(-\frac{4\Delta_{12} }{\Omega(t) }\right)a_x.\tag{2}$$
Since $J$ is a constant with respect to time and $\Omega(t)$ is not, technically $a_x$ will be time-dependent. However, in the link that you provided, the drive strength $\Omega(t)$ is assumed to be a constant $\Omega$, which means that $a_x$ can also be assumed to be a constant with respect to time.
